# Disable DataDog "Infrastructure Container" while still getting Kubernetes Logs and APM

Tags: kubernetes, datadog

we have the datadog agent [manually setup on our Kubernetes Cluster](https://docs.datadoghq.com/containers/guide/kubernetes_daemonset/) which helped us forwarding Logs and APM from our application containers into DataDog.

Recently we noticed the biggest item in our bill is "On-Demand Infrastructure Container Hours". Which seems to be related to this view: [image]

We really do not use that at all, and maybe we integrated incorrectly but right now we get no value out of it.

Is there a way of getting the Logs and APM from containers, but avoiding the big bill on this feature?

In the table on the manual installation it seems metrics is non-optional for the Agent. And I'm guessing this is what "metrics" is.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [Datadog docs](https://docs.datadoghq.com/account_management/billing/pricing/#infrastructure-monitoring), there are following items in the Infrastructure moniroting:

- containers (in case of k8s: pods)
- hosts (in case of k8s: nodes)
- etc.

What you're showing in the screenshot is the list of **Hosts**.

But the billing item "On-Demand Infrastructure Container Hours" refers to **Containers**.

To disable infra monitoring for some containers, you'd need to exclude them via the DD_CONTAINER_EXCLUDE env variable. [See the docs](https://docs.datadoghq.com/containers/guide/autodiscovery-management/?tab=containerizedagent)

E.g. to exclude ALL containers:

```
DD_CONTAINER_EXCLUDE = "name:.*"
```

Bonus:
To also disable **Hosts** monitoring there's a less obvious configuration that needs to be applied ([see docs](https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/guide/how-to-set-up-only-logs/?tab=kubernetes)) - add the following env variables to disable certain payloads:

```
env:
  - name: DD_ENABLE_PAYLOADS_EVENTS
    value: "false"
  - name: DD_ENABLE_PAYLOADS_SERIES
    value: "false"
  - name: DD_ENABLE_PAYLOADS_SERVICE_CHECKS
    value: "false"
  - name: DD_ENABLE_PAYLOADS_SKETCHES
    value: "false"
```

However as per docs, it may affect the logs collecting, so please verify if it affects your particular case.

Comment: This is awesome, thanks. And about `infrasctructure > hosts`. Right now, "Infra Hosts" and "APM Hosts" are the 2 biggest items in my usage. Is there a way to get rid of Infra Hosts without geting rid of APM?

Comment: @chamini2 I've added the configuration that worked for me to the answer above